# Having trouble with HP SCC installation

Tags: database, seeding

I am trying to install HP SSC but during installation when I reach the "seed process template" I get the error shown in the screenshot. I need help on this. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your database connection is successful then there can be only one reason of failure this connectivity. 
-Database collation is not set properly (Note: in older version it was optional but in new version you have to set it case sensitive (It must be having something like *CS* rather *CI* in its name)

If it didn't resolve your issue then please paste your code here.